how to use sendAndConfirmTransaction?
so i have a solana program and i wanted to sign the transaction so they can write to the program on the frontend. but the thing is, sendAndConfirmTransaction need a wallet object that has a secret key type to assign it to the signer parameter, but AnchorWallet doesnt have it. so how do to actually send a transaction?
code example
const a = await program.methods
                    .instruction(value)
                    .accounts({
                        account: accountAddress
                    })
                    .transaction()

                a.recentBlockhash = blockhash
                a.feePayer = wallet.publicKey

                const signedTransaction = await provider.wallet.signTransaction(initializeVote)

                const transaction = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, signedTransaction, []) //emptying the signer parameter cause idk what to put there


The AnchorProvider Class also includes a sendAndConfirm method that will use the AnchorWallet to sign. Check out the source code here.
With your code, it will look something like this:
const a = await program.methods
    .instruction(value)
    .accounts({
        account: accountAddress
    })
    .transaction()

const signature = await this.provider.sendAndConfirm(a, undefined, { commitment: "confirmed" });

The method will set the feepayer and get a blockhash for you.
